# how to add labels of points next to it based on index in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling, index, indexing

I have a list of some points. I plotted each point and its closest surrounding points.

```
points = Import[
   "/Users/Desktop/100nm12.txt", "Data"];
data = Table[{points[[i]][[1]], points[[i]][[2]]}, {i, 1, Length[points]}]

(*data here is imported in form of x,y coordinates*)
(*I am going to skip the part where I calculate position of each particle and its neighbors.*) 

pPar[i_] := 
 ListPlot[{data[[i]]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.1], Black], 
  PlotRange -> {{760, 830}, {0, 700}}]

pNeighbs2[i_] := 
 ListPlot[Table[data[[listy[i][[j]]]], {j, 1, Length[listy[i]]}], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.1], Red], 
  PlotRange -> {{data[[i]][[1]] - 20, 
     data[[i]][[1]] + 20}, {data[[i]][[2]] - 20, 
     data[[i]][[2]] + 20}}]

(*Here listy is the index of each neighboring point, calculated before*)

Table[Show[pNeighbs2[ii], pPar[ii] ], {ii, 200, 205}]
```

The result shows like this image,

I want to label each point (both reds and blacks) with its index next to it.

[image]

Comment: hi. Your code does not run. I get lots of errors, missing data, etc...

Comment: Well I excluded the part of the code where you generate a list because it is very lengthy

Comment: to make it easy to answer you, one needs to run your code. How else do you expect someone to answer you otherwise?  You could always make a MWE.

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[300, {300, 2}];
```

Construct lists of neighbors within radius `20` of each point using [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html):

```
r = 20;
listy = Association @ 
   MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> Rest@Nearest[data -> "Index", #, {All, r}] &, data];
```

You can wrap each data point with [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html):

```
pPar[i_] := ListPlot[{Callout[data[[i]], i]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotStyle -> Black, 
  PlotRange -> ({-20, 20} + # & /@ data[[i]])]

pNeighbs2[i_] := ListPlot[Table[Callout[data[[listy[i][[j]]]], listy[i][[j]]], {j, 1, 
    Length[listy[i]]}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> ({-20, 20} + # & /@ data[[i]])]

Row[Table[Show[pNeighbs2[ii], pPar[ii], ImageSize -> 1 -> 4], {ii, 200, 204}],
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Slightly more convenient approach is to plot a point and its neighbors in a single `ListPlot` to avoid overlapping labels:

```
ClearAll[color, lP]
color[1] = Black;
color[_] := Red;
lP = ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> (Function[x, {-20, 20} + x] /@ #[[1, 1, 1]]), ##2] &; 

assoc = Association @ MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> 
  MapIndexed[Callout[Style[data[[#]], Directive[PointSize[Large], color[#2[[1]]]]], #] &, 
      Nearest[data -> "Index", #, {All, r}]] &, 
  data];

Row[lP[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 4, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ 
  assoc /@ Range[200, 204], Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Partition[
  lP[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 4, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False] & /@ 
    assoc /@ Range[100, 114], 5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am trying your first approach but my version of mathematica 9 doesn't seem to know `Callout` , do you know how to call it ?

Comment: @Erf, `Callout` is available in versions 10+. For versions before v10.0  replace `Callout` with `Labeled` (you lose the connector lines between the points and labels)